# ReactJS - Pass references between siblings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, tree, siblings

I am currently having a problem building my ReactJS app. I have an array that takes this form:

```
[{
   _id: 123456,
   ...
   children: [
      {
         _id: 568,
         ...
         children: [...] // and so on, recursively
      },
      ....
   ]
}]
```

This architecture needs to be rendered as some "evolution tree", as in:

```
| item | => | item's first child  | => | first child's first child | ..
|      | => | item's second child |
```

Where each "item" or "child" is a component (called `EvolutionStep`), and each "=>" arrow is another component (called `EvolutionArrow`). So we have three components:

```
Evolution Chain => parent component, that renders
Evolution Step => containing the evolution props (name, etc)
Evolution Arrow => linking one step to one of it's children.
```

The evolution Arrow needs to point in the direction where the next Evolution Step is rendered (in the example, the first arrow between item and item's first child will point straight, but if the item's first child's position is like `{top: -20px}` the arrow should point a bit upwards.

In order to achieve this, each Evolution Step, when rendered, calls a function in Evolution Chain to add its reference to the local state. And each Evolution Arrow, when rendered, gets passed the reference to the Evolution Step it should point to. The problem is that Evolution Arrow's `reference` prop is always undefined...

I don't know if I explained myself correctly, so here is my code. Notice that if in the Evolution Arrow class you put a console.log(this.props.references), it is always undefined.

Thanks in advance for your help !

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

class EvolutionStep extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.mountCallable(this.props.step._id, this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{width: this.props.width + "%"}} data-identifier={this.props.step._id}>step</div>
        );
    };

}

class EvolutionArrow extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>arrow</div>
        );
    }
}

const EvolutionChain = class EvolutionChain extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.processStack.bind(this);
        this.stepDidMount.bind(this);
        this.preRender.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            cols: 0,
            chainData: [],
            refs: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.processStack();
    }

    stepDidMount(step_id, element) {
        let refs = this.state.refs;

        if (undefined == typeof(refs[step_id])) {
            refs[step_id] = element;
            this.setState({refs: refs});
        }
    }

    processStack() {
        if (null == this.props.chain) {
            return null;
        }

        let stack = [this.props.chain.children[0]];
        let results = [];

        while (stack.length > 0) {
            const current = stack.pop();
            // build current element
            results.push({type: 'step', props: {step: current} });
//            results.push(<EvolutionStep key={current._id} ref={(step) => this.addRef(current._id, step)} step={current} width={(100 / this.state.cols)}/>);
            this.setState({cols: this.state.cols + 1});
            if (current.children.length > 0) {
                let arrows = [];
                current.children.map((item) => {
                    arrows.push({pointsTo: item._id});
                    //arrows.push(<EvolutionArrow pointsTo={item._id} references={this.state.refs}/>);
                });
//                results.push(<div className="arrow" width={(100 / this.state.cols)}>{arrows}</div>);
                results.push({type: 'arrows', arrows: arrows});
                this.setState({cols: this.state.cols + 1});
                stack = current.children;
            }
        }

        results.reverse();
        this.setState({chainData: results});
    }

    preRender() {
        var components = [];
        this.state.chainData.map((item) => {
            switch (item.type) {
                case 'step':
                    components.push(<EvolutionStep key={item.props.step._id} {...item.props} mountCallable={(step_id, elem) => this.stepDidMount(step_id, elem)}/>);
                    break;
                case 'arrows':
                    let arrows = [];
                    item.arrows.map((arrow) => {
                        arrows.push(<EvolutionArrow pointsTo={arrow.pointsTo} references={this.state.refs[arrow.pointsTo]} />);
                    });
                    components.push(<div className="arrow">{arrows}</div>);
                    break;
            }
        });

        return components;
    }

    render() {

        let toRender = this.preRender();
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                {toRender}
            </div>
        );
    }

};

/** TODO: PropTypes **/

export default EvolutionChain;
```

Comment: So is `stepDidMount` getting called or not?

Comment: `stepDidMount` is indeed called, and gets passed the element and the right `step_id`. It just seems that the state update isn't propagated down to the children, as the `references` prop of all the `EvolutionArrow` components remains `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it ! All I had to do is wrap `undefined` in quotes in `stepDidMount`, otherwise the condition was always false...

Answer (score 0):

**refs** and **componentDidMount()** do the trick.

The following code helps me to setup communication between two siblings. The setup is done in their parent during render() and componentDidMount() calls.
It is based on https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
    private _navigationPanel: NavigationPanel;
    private _mapPanel: MapPanel;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }

    // `componentDidMount()` is called by ReactJS after `render()`
    componentDidMount() {
        // Pass _mapPanel to _navigationPanel
        // It will allow _navigationPanel to call _mapPanel directly
        this._navigationPanel.setMapPanel(this._mapPanel);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="appDiv" style={divStyle}>
                // `ref=` helps to get reference to a child during rendering
                <NavigationPanel ref={(child) => { this._navigationPanel = child; }} />
                <MapPanel ref={(child) => { this._mapPanel = child; }} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```